# How to free wasted space used by docker?

Tags: docker, build, diskspace

I set up docker on my server. I use Jenkins for CI. Those tools are really cool. But, unfortunately, I still can't figure out how to get the wasted space back.

I tried different things proposed on the web and by using them I can only free a part of the wasted space. I need no any history and etc.

I tried different things, like rude `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` and `docker rmi $(docker images -q)` while some of containers are running that make them prevented from deletion.

I also tried this script and similar.

```
#!/bin/bash

# remove exited containers:
docker ps --filter status=dead --filter status=exited -aq | xargs -r docker rm -v

# remove unused images:
docker images --no-trunc | grep '<none>' | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs -r docker rmi

# remove unused volumes:
find '/var/lib/docker/volumes/' -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -vFf <(
  docker ps -aq | xargs docker inspect | jq -r '.[] | .Mounts | .[] | .Name | select(.)'
) | xargs -r rm -fr
```

I would like to expect that after first build of all images I have fixed size of the stuff by applying the clean up commands above. In other words I want the subsequent builds with clean up applied doesn't make the wasted space grow.

But anyway every execution of docker build occupies new space that I can't free up.

The directory /var/lib/docker/overlay grows up and doesn't consider my clean ups eventually.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: docker build creates images, post `docker images` maybe you have many unused images?

Comment: no, the above scripts delete unused images, I see it if I have any

Answer (score 4):

In the latest versions of Docker, you can now use `docker system prune` command (with `--all` option for complete cleanup).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove volumes use:

```
docker volume prune
```

In order to remove networks use:

```
docker network prune
```

In order to remove all stopped containers use:

```
docker container prune
```

In order to remove unused images use:

```
docker image prune
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have an old version of docker: Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638. Sorry for the delay I was away...